# php pecl extension - compiling for win 8.1

Tags: php, pecl

I would like to compile the php pecl extension ev http://pecl.php.net/package/ev for PHP 5.5+ into a dll-file on Win 8.1 64-Bit.

I have already downloaded the ev source-code and already installed Visual Studio Express(!) 2012. What do i have to do next? How can i compile the source-code?

There is no file->new->project from existing code in Visual Studio Express(!).

I have also already tried to install the pecl exptension with the pecl command. But this doesn´t work:

> C:\xampp\php>pecl install ev No releases available for package
>   "pecl.php.net/ev" install failed

Answer (score 0):

Check install.md file there are all informations what you need.
To be honest you can't install it doing with pecl command because there is information:

> Currently GNU/Linux platforms supported only.

There is also manual installation guide but probably you would need to do it with MinGW/MySYS if any. I suppose you would need to edit sources.

Comment: > Check install.md file there are all informations what you need

Ok, thank you. So i will have to use pthreads.

But unfortunately i get an error:

> C:\xampp\php>pecl install -R C:\xampp\ pthreads downloading
> pthreads-2.0.7.tgz ... Starting to download pthreads-2.0.7.tgz (77,570
> bytes) ..................done: 77,570 bytes 34 source files, building
> WARNING: php_bin C:\xampp\php\.\php.exe appears to have a suffix
> \.\php.exe, but  config variable php_suffix does not match ERROR: The
> DSP pthreads.dsp does not exist.

Comment: i changed the setting for php_suffix: # pecl config-set php_suffix \php.exe
config-set succeeded

Comment: But i still get an error: # pecl install pthreads
downloading pthreads-2.0.7.tgz ...
Starting to download pthreads-2.0.7.tgz (77,570 bytes)
..................done: 77,570 bytes
34 source files, building
ERROR: The DSP pthreads.dsp does not exist.

Comment: I used the shell of the XAMPP Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

mingw-w64 project has replaced mingw and mingw-build.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/4.9.1/threads-posix/sjlj/

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/4.9.1/threads-posix/sjlj/

you can of course pick a different version number by going up to a parent dir in the file tree. for example, if you look in the personal builds, you would find the most up-to-date:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/dongsheng-daily/4.9/

gcc uses not .lib files but instead .a files for libs, and php includes a .lib for devs, so immediately I know it's for VC++ (and it was compiled with that and it says so for the windows target download).
after you have correctly configured MSYS (not an easy job),

```
./configure;make;make install

./configure gives me the error:
configure: error: xml2-config not found. Please check your libxml2 installation.
```

libxml2 requires python, which certain windows antivirus packages remove from mingw-w64.